# ReactJS file upload Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am having form with 4 file upload fields, that users can submit up to 4 images.

I am adding files to array, loop and upload to server with PHP.

Now everything seams to be working fine.. but returned image names (I am using those to store in DB) are not in the same order as I am uploading them:

Here is example of code:

```
if (postImage1 !== null) {
                postImagesArray.push(postImage1);
            }
            if (postImage2 !== null) {
                postImagesArray.push(postImage2);
            }
            if (postImage3 !== null) {
                postImagesArray.push(postImage3);
            }
            if (postImage4 !== null) {
                postImagesArray.push(postImage4);
            }
            //Loop Array and make upload......
            var startCount = 1;
            var endCount = postImagesArray.length;
            for (var i = 0; i < postImagesArray.length; i++) {
                var currentImage = postImagesArray[i];
                //##### UPLOADING IMAGE ###########
                try {
                    var base_url = 'https://##############.com/uploadImage.php';
                    var fd = new FormData();
                    fd.append('avatar', currentImage, 'post.jpg');
                    axios.post(base_url, fd).then((res) => {
                        console.log(res);
                        if (res.data.status === 'success') {
                            let fileConstruct =
                                'https://############.com/' +
                                res.data.fileName +
                                '?fit=crop&w=840&q=80';
                            uploadImagesArray.push(fileConstruct);
                        } else {
                            // there was an error with file upload... revert to default...
                            console.log('No error but no image either......');
                        }
                        if (startCount == endCount) {
                            uploadImagesConstruct();
                        }
                        startCount++;
                    });
                } catch (err) {
                    //console.error(err);
                    console.log(
                        'There was an error uploading file to the web server: ' + err
                    );
                    if (startCount == endCount) {
                        uploadImagesConstruct();
                    }
                }
```

Interesting thing is, images are mixed up always in the same order... (so it is not random), instead of returned image1,image2,image3,image4 I am getting image3, image2, image4, image1....If I post only 2 images it is image2,image1.... so first image is always returned last.....

Can anybody see what I am doing wrong..

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Can you console.log and see the order in which you are sending the images? You need to first see if Request and Response has the same order of images.

Comment: Yes... sorry I forgot to mention that.. I am sending it in correct order according to logs, but response is not in the same order.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone need this in the future....

I simply added underscore and postion in the loop "_i" before ".jpg" when I am constructing file names..

```
fd.append('avatar', currentImage, 'post.jpg');
```

now is:

```
fd.append('avatar', currentImage, `post_${i}.jpg`);
```

and since I am putting all records in the array

```
uploadImagesArray.push(fileConstruct);
```

I just resorted it.. by the numbers I added..

```
uploadImagesArray.sort(function(x, y) {
                var xp = x.substring(x.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, x.lastIndexOf('.jpg'));
                var yp = y.substring(y.lastIndexOf('_') + 1, y.lastIndexOf('.jpg'));
                return xp == yp ? 0 : xp < yp ? -1 : 1;
            });
```

Comment: Instead of add this complexity to the frontend. The backend API should properly add the images in the order you have sent and send the response in the order of `created_at_time`. This operation costs less on the backend than on the frontend.